# What is the point of ./ in ./images?

Tags: url, uri

I have encountered multiple CSS specifications where the images are referred to like this:

```
./images/bg.jpg
```

I understand that `./` means "this directory", so what is the difference between `./images/bg.jpg` and `images/bg.jpg`?  Why would a developer use `./` in a URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct - there's no difference between the two, so really it's just the individual developer's preference. There's not much more to say about the subject!

Comment: @iMoses Well, on linux you'll usually use `./` to explicitly state you want a file from the current directory, rather than one available somewhere else in the environment's `PATH` (which could be dangerous if a typo could turn something like `rmo` into `rm`)- so I'm guessing that's where the habit comes from

Comment: Thanks for the info about where this convention may have come from!

Answer (score 2):

There's no major difference between the two, but I will [quote Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Unix_style) on this one, as it's possible theoretically, but highly unlikely in practice:

> Using "./foo" to refer to a file "foo" in the current working directory can sometimes usefully distinguish it from a resource "foo" to be found in a default directory or by other means; for example, to view a specific version of a manual page instead of the one installed in the system

Additionally, it's possible that some organizations might decide to implement declaring both `.` and `..` for relative paths as a convention.